# How to use site_name variable in other view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to user site_title in my footer,

But I don't know how to access the `site_tile` variable

### active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  config.site_title = "MY SITE NAME"


module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Footer < Component

      def build
        div do
          large "#{ActiveAdmin::config.site_title} #{Date.today.year}"
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Rails config stuff can be accessed through:
`Rails.application.config.<your_variable>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the above, you can define the footer in the en.yml.

```
en:
  active_admin:
    powered_by: "Powered by you. Copyright 2014 @ stackoverflow"
```

It's a more easier way of approach and can be used anywhere in the application.